# Read a pdf file to text file in python 3, but it generates an error like AttributeError: 'PDFObjRef' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, pdfminer, pdftotext

## Reading pdf file to extract text in python3 using pdfminer library(I installed the package using pip install pdfminer.six)

```
import io
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def pdfparser(data):

    fp = open(data, 'rb')
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    # Create a PDF interpreter object.

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    # Process each page contained in the document.


    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        data =  retstr.getvalue()
    print(data)
```

Comment: Your code works without errors on my end. What is `data` that you pass to `pdfparser`? Is it the PDF's filename as a string? Try running it outside of the function and using [simple1.pdf](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/tree/master/samples) from pdfminer.six's repo.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am trying to read mobile postpaid bill pdf file and get the text out of it. Its a Vodafone postpaid bill. It still shows the same error at my end.